# dynamic orderBy not working with ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I'm having trouble getting the list ordered based on the selected value.
What would be considered a better practice for this?

```
<select ng-model='selected'>
            <option value="name">Name</option>
            <option value="score">Score</option>

</select>

<ul ng-repeat="shop in shops track by $index | orderBy: 'data.{{selected}}' ">

            <li class="name">{{shop.data.name}}</li>
            <li class="score">Score: {{shop.data.score}}</li>
            <li><img  ng-src="{{shop.data.img}}"> </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Try to remove `'` and `'` from `orderBy: 'data.{{selected}}'` - JS interprete this as string value, but you want to use object from your controller, as I suppose

Comment: and remove brackets and `data` - so try something like `<ul ng-repeat="shop in shops track by $index | orderBy: selected ">`

Comment: here is my NOT working js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hoo2g0o4/5/

Comment: only two changes are needed in your fiddle:
1) in selected values add `data.name` instead of `name` - object properties arent visible directly ;)
2) put `track by $index` after filter

Comment: I have updated fiddle.Please check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here what I have tried.

HTML :

```
<select ng-model="selected"> 
            <option value="name">Name</option>
            <option value="score">Score</option> 
        </select>

        <ul ng-repeat="shop in shops | orderBy:selected">

        <li class="name">{{shop.name}}</li>
        <li class="score">Score: {{shop.score}}</li>

        </ul>
```

JS :

```
$scope.shops= [     {name : "A",score : 13},
                        {name : "B",score : 11},
                        {name : "C",score : 12},
                        {name : "A",score : 11},
                        {name : "B",score : 12},
                        {name : "C",score : 11}

                    ];
```

I think you should remove **track by** from our ng-repeat.

EDIT :

your ng-repeat should be like this

```
<ul ng-repeat="shop in shops | orderBy: selected ">
```

Please refer this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KzwtBeoNveEJ1QWCcdjx?p=preview)

Please refer to your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hoo2g0o4/11/)

Comment: Thanks for your help, it seems my problem is in the nested object inside the shops object
http://plnkr.co/edit/zpzBIcO6axZWcNL1b2lh?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

The following ng-repeat should do the trick

```
<ul ng-repeat="shop in shops | orderBy: selected track by $index  ">
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/divm/hoo2g0o4/3/) is a working example

Comment: For some reason the example is not working for me, strange